# Ajax response data type not matched

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

```
 success: function(response){
                console.log(response);
                if(response === 1){
                    alert('<p>New booking added !</p>');
                }
            }
```

My ajax working fine but when i am matching response to show message its not working... In console is showing 1 then what else would be the reason of not showing alert ??

This 1 is being displayed by PHP from below code.

```
/**
 * Add new booking 
 */
if (isset($_POST['newbooking'])) {
    unset($_POST['newbooking']);
    $arg = $_POST;
    $booking = new Bookings;
    if ($new_booking = $booking->Add_Booking($arg)) {
        $room = new Rooms;
        // Set room status to reserved
        $room->Set_Room_Status($new_booking, 2);

        echo 1; // successfull
    } else {
        echo 0; // something happens wrong
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Try `parseInt(response) === 1`

Comment: nope :S still not showing any alert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `===` comparison operator means "exactly equal to", returns true if the operands are equal *and* of the same type. Since you compare a text response with expected integer type, the expression will always fail.

use

```
if (response == '1') {
   alert('<p>New booking added !</p>');
}
```

instead. Btw, `alert` does not translate `<p>`-tags.

Comment: yes i know your point bro, but thats what i am asking that even i m returning integer from php why ajax is treating as string ?

Comment: All responses are treated as strings.

Comment: because there is no such response dataType as "integer" or "number". How should the client tell that you serverside had made `echo 1;` and not `echo "1";`? A response will always be text with or without certain expected formatting, like JSON or XML.

Comment: oh...That was my lack of knowledge... Thank you so much

Comment: @davidkonrad but what i am returning true or false from server side.. how can i matched that in jquery ?

Comment: the same -> `if (response == 'true')`. I think your 0/1 is very good and sufficient when it only is a flag.